# Why do objects appear in queue after agents were removed?

Tags: animation, anylogic

I have a simple DES model where spheres pass through 4 stations whose delay times are adjusted by parameters connected to sliders. I flood the system with variation at two stations and I'd like to clear the stations and queues. See images and code in photos. After the reset, an image of the sphere remains in the lower right corner of the queue location even though there are no agents in the queue and the queue size is 0. Why does this image remain here?

[image: Before Reset]

[image: After Reset]

[image: Reset Action Code]

Answer (score 2):

You removed the agents from the queue but did not destroy the agents. So they just continue to "live" somewhere and seem to choose the bottom right corner as the default animation position. They probably also all stack on top of each other.

Either destroy them as well or use the `jumpTo(x,y)` method to move them out of sight

Comment: How would you destroy them? I've tried `remove_balls();` `remove_balls(ball);` and get an undefined method for the type Main error. I was able to do what I wanted with [link]https://stackoverflow.com/a/56061386/12380729

Comment: You must call the `remove_MyPop(...)` method where the population lives. If it is on `Main`, you can only call it there, else you need to "navigate" to where it is first. Check the help on model hierarchy and structure to understand OOP structures